# How to create an image with transparent background

Tags: php, gdlib

How to create an image with GDlib with a transparent background?

```
header('content-type: image/png');

$image = imagecreatetruecolor(900, 350);

imagealphablending($image, true);
imagesavealpha($image, true);

$text_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 51, 102);
imagestring($image,2,4,4,'Test',$text_color);

imagepng($image);
imagedestroy($image);
```

Here the background is black

Comment: you have to use `imagefill` and fill that with allocated color (imagecolorallocatealpha) that have alpha set to 0.

Comment: @noice, create an answer.. it works

Comment: @NoICE: allocating the color is not necessary, it is a true color image.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to use `imagefill()` and fill that with allocated color (`imagecolorallocatealpha()`) that have alpha set to 0.

As @mvds said, "allocating isn't necessary", if it is a truecolor image (24 or 32bit) it is just an integer, so you can pass that integer directly to `imagefill()`.

What PHP does in the background for truecolor images when you call `imagecolorallocate()` is the same thing - it just returns that computed integer.

Answer (score 31):

Add a line

```
imagefill($image,0,0,0x7fff0000);
```

somewhere before the `imagestring` and it will be transparent.

`0x7fff0000` breaks down into:

```
alpha = 0x7f
red = 0xff
green = 0x00
blue = 0x00
```

which is fully transparent.

Answer (score 14):

Something like this...

```
$im = @imagecreatetruecolor(100, 25);
# important part one
imagesavealpha($im, true);
imagealphablending($im, false);
# important part two
$white = imagecolorallocatealpha($im, 255, 255, 255, 127);
imagefill($im, 0, 0, $white);
# do whatever you want with transparent image
$lime = imagecolorallocate($im, 204, 255, 51);
imagettftext($im, $font, 0, 0, $font - 3, $lime, "captcha.ttf", $string);
header("Content-type: image/png");
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

Comment: This made my transparent background white instead of black :(

Comment: i want to generate a image with dimension equal to text length how i can achieve that? without giving static parameter(100,25) to function @imagecreatetruecolor(100, 25);

Answer (score 8):

This should work:

```
$img = imagecreatetruecolor(900, 350);

$color = imagecolorallocatealpha($img, 0, 0, 0, 127); //fill transparent back
imagefill($img, 0, 0, $color);
imagesavealpha($img, true);
```

Answer (score 7):

This should work. It has worked for me.

```
$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth,$newheight);
$transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($thumb, 0, 0, 0, 127);
imagefill($thumb, 0, 0, $transparent);
imagesavealpha($thumb, true);
imagecopyresampled($thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);
imagepng($thumb, $output_dir);
```

Comment: Code only answers arent encouraged as they dont provide much information for future readers please provide some explanation to what you have written

Comment: The function `imagesavealpha()` saved my day. Documentation says: `sets the flag to attempt to save full alpha channel information (as opposed to single-color transparency) when saving PNG images`

Answer (score 1):

Sometime you will not get transparent image due to problems in PNG image. The image should be in one of the following recommended formats:

```
PNG-8 (recommended)
Colors: 256 or less
Transparency: On/Off
GIF
Colors: 256 or less
Transparency: On/Off
JPEG
Colors: True color
Transparency: n/a
```

The imagecopymerge function does not properly handle the PNG-24 images; it is therefore not recommend.

If you are using Adobe Photoshop to create watermark images, it is recommended that you use "Save for Web" command with the following settings:

```
File Format: PNG-8, non-interlaced
Color Reduction: Selective, 256 colors
Dithering: Diffusion, 88%
Transparency: On, Matte: None
Transparency Dither: Diffusion Transparency Dither, 100%
```